# How do I get annotations working for JSF2 in Netbeans?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I added and have been using the faces-config.xml in my Netbeans 6.9/JSF2.0 project due to annotations not working.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I use annotations, my beans are completely inaccessible.  Properties for the project show that it is indeed JSF 2.0 (and not 1.1).

Comment: What annotations do you use, CDI or JSF? How do you deploy your application? What app server do you use? Did you check the server logs?

Comment: JSF.  Running it through Netbeans.  Glassfish v3.  Logs don't show anything different at all vs when it works with the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-solved.  Capitalization issue.  With the annotations, the bean name (inside the xhtml) needs to have a leading lower case character, even though the class is capitalized.  With the XML faces configuration file, it worked fine capitalized...

Comment: It also makes sense as per Sun Java naming conventions. Variable names needs to start with lowercase. You would also write in real Java code like `Bean bean = new Bean()` and not `Bean Bean = new Bean()` ;) If you really insist using capitalized bean instance names, then make use of `name` attribute of `@ManagedBean` annotation to override the default one.